# Having trouble installing GDAL for python in gitbash

Tags: python, gdal

This is what I did in git bash.

```
 pip install gdal
```

and the result is:

```
  error: Microsoft Visual C++ 14.0 or greater is required. Get it with "Microsoft C++ Build Tools": https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/visual-cpp-build-tools/
  [end of output]

  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
error: legacy-install-failure

Encountered error while trying to install package.

gdal

note: This is an issue with the package mentioned above, not pip.
hint: See above for output from the failure.
```

I really don't know what to do. I even tried to install " Microsoft C++ Build Tools " but I already installed so I downloaded C+ packages.

Comment: very few 'python' modules require the Microsoft C++ Build Tools. I know that this is not a solution, but try to avoid them where possible.

Comment: Another option is installing GDAL via Anaconda.